# Why is center align not working through CSS?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code,

```
<ul class="list-group">
      <li style="background: #F3F3F3;" class="list-group-item">
        <a href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        </a>
        <span class="center-class">Branch Details</span>
      </li>
</ul>
```

I want the *Branch Details* text to appear in the center. My CSS class is like this,

```
<style type="text/css">
  .center-class {
     text-align: center;
   }
</style>
```

Here's the code I'm working on - http://jsbin.com/vunicayiho/edit?html,output
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: you need a div or some other block-level element

Comment: The text _is_ centered - it just has little visible effect, because the element you are centering it in is only as wide as the text demands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said, the span is inline and doesn't extends to full width, and this cause the text seems not being centered. You could use bootstrap custom class to solve this:

In the `<li>` add class `clearfix` to expand the li to the content it owns, and then the bootstrap class `col-xs-1` and `col-xs-11` to fix the elements inside.

```
<li class="list-group-item clearfix" style="background: #F3F3F3;">
            <a data-slide="prev" role="button" href="#carousel-example-generic" class="col-xs-1">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            </a>
            <span class="center-class col-xs-11">Branch Details</span>
</li>
```

Then you only had to set the correct heigth, i.e:

```
.center-class {
    text-align: center;
    line-height:20px;
  }
```

And it works fine!

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! It helped :)

Answer (score 1):

It is because `<span>` is an inline element. So give the class to the `<li>`, also check your markup. That's messed up. Corrected one:

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li style="background: #F3F3F3;" class="list-group-item text-center">
    <a href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span>Branch Details</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Output: http://jsbin.com/barunefeku/1/edit?html,output**

Comment: Thanks for your response :) But I want the < arrow to remain left and just the Branch Details text alone in the center. Is that possible?

Comment: @KematRochi Yup, it is indeed possible. Sorry, before even reading your comment, I slept off. Else I would have solved it fully for you. Enjoy.